# EF core Unique Constraint violation, circular dependency

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, concurrency, entity-framework-core

I have a table called 'LineItem' table which has 'SortOrder and Bom_Fk' columns and there is Unique key constraint on these columns.

Suppose, the table has 2 rows as below

```
 ID | SortOrder| Bom_Fk 
 1  | 1        | 122
 2  | 2        | 122
```

Now, I am updating these rows as below

```
ID | SortORder| Bom_Fk
1  | 2        | 122
2  | 1        | 122
```

Just I am reversing the SortOrder of Line items.

Note that SortOrder is not null, Unique constraint

When trying to Update from EF core, this throws Unique constraint error while updating first line item as 2nd line item already has sort order as 2 in database.
So I thought of doing bulk update using UpdateRange(..), but this throws error as described below.

> Unable to save changes because a circular dependency was detected in
> the data to be saved: 'LineItem [Modified] <-\r\nIndex { 'BomFk',
> 'SortOrder' } LineItem [Modified] <-\r\nIndex { 'BomFk', 'SortOrder' }
> LineItem [Modified]To show additional information call
> 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging'.'."

Code used for updating to this table...

```
 lineItemsToUpdate.Add(lineItem);
 context.LineItems.UpdateRange(lineItemsToUpdate);
```

I am planning to make SortOrder null and make sure that it is not null from Code...
So that I can update all LineItems with null and then update with new values.(I am yet to try this , having null for Unique constraint is not a good idea but this is work around I am planning to try)

Is there any way I make it work keeping 'Sort Order as not null unique column'?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not really important if sortorder  value will be 1,2,3 or 101, 102, 103. I usually use hundreds or thousands for this. In this case it is easier to move item from one place to another.

So you can try this

```
var maxSortOrder= context.LineItems.Max(i=>i.SortOrder);

foreach(var item in lineItemsToUpdate)
{
maxSortOrder+=1;
item.SortOrder=maxSortOrder;
}
```

after this you can save the range.

If  sortOrder value is important,  after saving you can sort again using any numbers.

Another way is to use raw sql queries  to turn off and on unique constraint. But it is very unsafe and you will have a big problem if you have an error in your data. This feature is usually used to migrate data from one db or table to another.

Comment: Thank you @Sergey, It could be a possible work around  but one thing about get MaxOrder and adding to that is , it can run out of range at some point, there could be around 500 line items per (Bom_Fk, SortOrder) combination.